# What is a replacement for the deprecated Android Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Android is making some strange updates to the API/SDK related to Play Services. They have deprecated the `Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER` option and advice developers to stop using it.

See the docs here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

At the same time, their most recent examples (updated 20 days ago) on how to implement Play Services Saved Games use this scope and do not offer an alternative to using it.

See it here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/bd72ba919a8a840dec33e83def5e366816367a42/CollectAllTheStars2/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/catt2/MainActivity.java#L310

What we as developers using the Play Services Saved Games API should do to replace this scope?

And what the heck is happening with the Google Play Services ecosystem in recent years?

Things that just work are changed to confuse, not work, or be more complicated than previous versions (i.e. the new Saved Games API).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive scopes deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329863/google-drive-scopes-deprecated)

Comment: No for the case of using the Saved Games API. This API is written by Google and it requires having this scope to work. I cannot work around it by using a REST API, as it is (probably) used internally inside their Saved Games API. I don't call REST endpoints directly, I use the provided Play Services API which requires that scope.

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer is DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA (com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev197-1.25.0).

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
                .build()
```

Comment: For me at a day of writing it looks like this: `'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20230306-2.0.0'`